# WPF event handler for minimizing a Ribbon?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

Anyone know if the Ribbon control (using a Ribbon Window WPF project in VS 2010) has an event handler for when the tabs are minimized?

I tried looking around the events but I couldn't find anything that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the [Ribbon.Collapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.collapsed.aspx) event, or it's corresponding [Expanded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.expanded.aspx) event.

Comment: Sounds like it'll work, I'll check later today when I have time to code the program. I'll mark this as answered if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Its IsMinimizedChanged in older version. I am using version 2.0 and had to disable minimize functionality on ribbon.

IsMinimizedChanged event is called when the minimize button on ribbon is clicked or someone double click on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I inherited the Ribbon and added the following code to detect if Ribbon is being minimized or maximized:

```
Event IsMinimizedChanged As EventHandler

Private mIsMinimized As Boolean

Protected Overrides Sub OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(child As UIElement)
    MyBase.OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(child)
    If TypeOf child Is Grid Then
        If Not mIsMinimized = IsMinimized Then
            RaiseEvent IsMinimizedChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            mIsMinimized = IsMinimized
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```